# Передать Cookies с POST запросом jMeter

Tags: api, юнит-тесты, веб-сервер, jmeter

Тестирую web-api сервис. Не получается добавить Cookie в Post запрос jMeter. Использую `HTTP Cookie Manager` :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее кука должна отправляется в заголовке на сервер но ничего не происходит :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю неправильно ? Через постман все проходило элементарно, с jmeter начались тотальные проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вы собираетесь использовать политику `netscape` - домен не может начинаться с точки, просто введите туда хостнейм, например `.example.com` не пройдет, а `example.com` должно сработать
2. Если у вас нету жесткого требования следования правилам `netscape` - поменяйте политику на `standard`
3. Попробуйте добавить строку `CookieManager.check.cookies=false` в файл user.properties
4. И если уж совсем ничего не помогает добавьте строку [`<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />`](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) в файл *log4j2.xml* и смотрите на подозрительные записи в файле *jmeter.log*
5. Если вам позарез нужно отправить куку - это также можно сделать через [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) ибо это обычный [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#Cookies)

Comment: Через header manager тоже пробовал, но важно не просто отправить session_id но и обновить, ТК в ответе приходит новое значение.

Comment: Что это за файл user.properties ?

Comment: Конфигурационный файл JMeter, там можно задавать [кучу разных параметров](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html), живет в папке "bin". Можно переопределять все параметры через ключ `-J`, например запуская JMeter как `jmeter -JCookieManager.check.cookies=false -t test.jmx .....`. [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: попробовал в `Cookie Manager` убрать точку из домена и выставил политику `Standart`. в заголовки запроса добавился `Cookie` но проблема в том что получая ответ `Set-Cookie` - значение не обновляется. Каким я его выставил изначально таким и остается, хотя должно менятся.

Comment: В общем оказалось проблема совсем в другом была. Если посмотреть на 2 скрин с параметрами то ничего необычного, но когда я дважды нажал на параметр ЛКМ и открыл его во `View text` то обнаружил что текст расположен не с начала строки а с отступами. эти отступы и были причиной проблем.